# \resize.cpp:3787: error: (-215:Assertion failed) func != 0 in function 'cv::hal::resize'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am resizing a one-D array using opencv resize function but this give me the following error

```
\resize.cpp:3787: error: (-215:Assertion failed) func != 0 in function 'cv::hal::resize'

array=cv.resize(np.array(array),(1,10000), interpolation = cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Comment: the source array length is 75000+

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first parameter of cv.resize should be numpy uint8-typed array:

```
array = np.array(array, dtype='uint8')
cv.resize(array, (1, 10000), interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```