# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\ ... \modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) func != 0 in function 'cv::hal::resize'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-resizing

I tried to run the following code:

```
a = np.array([[1,0],[0,0]])
a = cv2.resize(a , (400,400))
cv2.imshow('Image', a)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

and got this error:

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_8k9tw8n\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) func != 0 in function 'cv::hal::resize'`

couldn't find any similar question

Answer (score 5):

the error is from the resize function, it needs to be a dtype=uint8 type array.
there is a pretty solid answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087860/resize-cpp3787-error-215assertion-failed-func-0-in-function-cvhal)

update me if it worked :)

Comment: uint8 is better suited

Comment: int8 didn't worked but float did. thanks!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz also uint8 worked, never heard of this dtype. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of you array a to ***float*** fix the issue.

> a = cv2.resize(a.astype(float) , (400,400))

[image]